# Events ID 2297 and 2307 in IIS (IIS-W3SVC-WP)

Tags: iis, web-applications, application-pools

For a couple of weeks, some applications in IIS have stopped responding, when trying to access the site, the app return the error:

[image]

On Windows Event Log, I found 2 events in the Application Log: 2297 and 2307:

```
The worker process for application pool 'Appname' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file
' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\AppName\AppName.config', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.
```

and:

```
The worker process for application pool 'CourrierTlsWeb' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file
' trying to read global module configuration data from file '\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\AppName\AppName.config', line number '0'.  Worker process startup aborted.
```

When this happens, we recycle the Application pool of the Webapp and the site return online. I have checked antivirus to see if it's blocking the config file, but haven't find any indicator that the AV could be blocking the file. I have also checked the disk but haven't found any error either. What could be causing these events?

This is running on Windows Server 2019 STD.

Best Regards.

**UPDATE**
Apparently the DFS has something to do with this. There are 2 IIS server that sync the configuration folder. I have followed this article:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/configuration-file-related-errors-in-a-shared-iis-environment/ba-p/334361

Comment: If you confirmed that DFS is the culprit, you might post and accept your answer below to close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being cause by DFS, as decribed in this post:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/configuration-file-related-errors-in-a-shared-iis-environment/ba-p/334361